# How to Stay on same page even I do refresh

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing one asp.net website.
I have page which contains menu items like Home,Aboutsus,Help.. like I have 5 tabs. in single page.
If I click on second tab and If I do refresh agian its going to home page.
How to stay on the same page even I refreshed the page.
Hope u understand my problem.
Pleas help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What tab are you using ? You search for a remember of the tab ?

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery history plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-history-web-2-0-hashchange-history-remote

When a user switches tab, change the hash. When the page is loaded, check the hash and move to that tab. You can also do it without using history plugin though.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you mentioned that you're using RadTabStrip. [Here](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/08-12-04/Easily_persist_RadTabStrip_Selected_Tab_using_client-side_API.aspx) is a blog post that describes how to fix your problem using the RabTabStrip's client-side API.

Answer (score 0):

you can save the page status inside `cookies` using `javascript` and read it again by `javascript` too.for example you can save the selected tab into a cookie and after the page has been refreshed set the selected tab id from a cookie.

this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp) explain how to set and retrieve cookies using javascript and this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)